# How to docker cloud? What i doing wrong?

Tags: docker, cloud, dashboard

my Dashboard is this:

[image: mydashboard]

But i see this on youtube:

[image: docker cloud]

how can i use this docker cloud? sorry for this stupid question.

Comment: Please consider taking the time to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then come back to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53383664/edit).

Answer (score 0):

Docker Cloud [shutdown most of its services in May 2018](https://success.docker.com/article/cloud-migration)